# Is memory in the sentence focus to remember or to remind?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, spoken-english

> She says, **laughing at the memory**. “The lab assistant just said, ‘Well,
> nobody’s ever done that before.’”

Thank you and will welcome an expert voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. We often use the noun 'memory' to refer to *a specific event in our memory.*

For example, speaking about a happy occasion in our past we might say either:

- What a happy day that *was*.
- What a happy memory that *is*.

From your quotation, it sounds like someone has recalled a previous occasion to mind and are now referring to that event as a 'memory'. Whether or not someone else reminded them of it, causing them to remember it, might be revealed by the surrounding text, but the word 'memory' itself does not reflect that.

Comment: one more thing, sitting alone and clicked particular occasion in mind or while talking to someone and some past memory pops up?